# Verify app invite server-side

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

When our mobile app user sends app-invite to fb user and he accepts it, the server should give a reward to the first one. So I need a way to verify whether the invite was sent.

```
        var fb = new FacebookClient(APP_ID + "|" + SECRET_ID);
        fb.AppId = APP_ID;
        fb.AppSecret = SECRET_ID;
        dynamic result = fb.Get(???);
```

I searched on GraphAPI docs and it seems that I need to retrieve users apprequests. How to do that from the server side and where to look at to perform such verification?

**UPDATE**

Ok, now I know that it's [allowed to reward only for accepted invites](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t39.2178-6/851566_549981185101135_1548011715_n.png). I can record who invites who in the db and give a reward only when a new invited user joins. But I still need a way to verify that these invites were actually sent.

**UPDATE2**

As the documentation states apprequests call from application returns all the requests sent from this application. So I think it would be enough for me to just check that there are any requests from this app:

```
        dynamic result = fb.Get("/" + facebookId + "/apprequests");
        IEnumerable data = result.data;
        return data.Cast<object>().Count() != 0;
```

But I can't check it now. Can anyone confirm that if a user sends invite to app to another user this invite will be seen through apprequests from the application access token?

Comment: You are not allowed to give rewards for sending invites according to https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Comment: can you give a quote please?

Comment: 4.5: "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, like your app’s Page, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions. (Effective November 5th, 2014, you may no longer incentivize people to like your app's Page)."

Comment: @WizKid is it allowed to reward users for connecting their game account to facebook?

Comment: In 4.5 example screens: it's ok to reward for invites which are accepted by other users. https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t39.2178-6/851566_549981185101135_1548011715_n.png

Comment: Yes. But that was not what you said you were going to do

Comment: _“But I still need a way to verify that these invites were actually sent”_ – when a user acts upon an invite, you get the request id(s) passed via URL parameter, and with those you can fetch the details of the request objects from the API, including the information which user send the invite. That should be all you need to verify that a request was actually send by user A to user B, to reward A for the successful invite – because if A did not send any invite, then there would also be no request object that you could look up via API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it:

```
    public static bool CheckInvite(string fromId, string toId)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(APP_ID + "|" + SECRET_ID);
        fb.AppId = APP_ID;
        fb.AppSecret = SECRET_ID;
        dynamic result = fb.Get(string.Format("/{0}/apprequests", toId));
        foreach (var el in result.data)
            if ((string)el.from.id == fromId)
            {
                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse((string)el.created_time, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                if ((DateTime.Now - dateTime).TotalMinutes < 15)
                {
                        return true;
                }
            }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This approach suits me better than suggested by razon - response by request id does not contain "to" property (if you does not specify a request with to-id included like 123456_234567).

Answer (score 0):

my code for this:

```
        public static FacebookRequestData GetInviteHash()
        {
            string requestId = Request["request_ids"];
            var accessToken = GetAccessToken(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookSecret"]);

            string response;
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                response = webClient.DownloadString(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}?{1}", requestId, accessToken));
            }

            var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            return javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<FacebookRequestData>(javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<FacebookRequestInfo>(response).data);
        }

        private static string GetAccessToken(string appId, string password)
        {
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                return webClient.DownloadString(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials", appId, password));
            }
        }

        private class FacebookRequestInfo
        {
            public string data { get; set; }
        }
```

FacebookRequestData - my custom class with structure of fields that I posted to fb earlier